# Is it possible to boot the Raspberry Pi in Secure Mode?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bare-metal, trustzone

I am currently developing a small OS on my Raspberry Pi, that I install by replacing the `kernel.img` file on the `/boot partition` of my SD card. By the time my code is run, the CPU is already in Normal Mode, so I can't have access to the Secure world / Trustzone area.

Is it possible to modify the boot process of the Raspberry to be able to start executing my code in Secure mode ?

Best,
V.

Comment: You might get a better response asking this on the Raspberry Pi site: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh right, I didn't know about this site, thanks :) I'll close this one and point to the other site if I get an answer there. Thank you !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [it has been re-asked and answered on Raspberry Pi SE](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14953/is-it-possible-to-boot-the-raspberry-pi-in-secure-mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you don't have to do anything but stop being stupid like me.
As explained here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14953/is-it-possible-to-boot-the-raspberry-pi-in-secure-mode

When the `NS` bit of the `SCR` register is 0, it means that you are in Secure Mode, which is the case at boot on my Raspberry. I had the meaning of this bit backwards, sorry !